# Updating Oracle database throws illegal variable name/number exception

Tags: c#, oracle, exception

I'm trying to update a table in an Oracle database. This code with hard-coded state code works and updates the record:

```
public WorkRates UpdateRecord(int id, string stateCode)
{
    var sql = "update work_rates set state_code = 'WA' where id = :id";
    var db = Db.Load(sql);

    db.AddParameter(":id", id);

    db.DoExecute();

    return null;
}
```

When I change it to this:

```
public WorkRates UpdateRecord(int id, string stateCode)
{
    var sql = "update work_rates set state_code = :stateCode where id = :id";
    var db = Db.Load(sql);

    db.AddParameter(":id", id);
    db.AddParameter(":stateCode", stateCode);

    db.DoExecute();

    return null;
}
```

... it throws exception "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number". The function public WorkRates UpdateRecord(int id, string stateCode) does get the right value for stateCode ('WA'). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: does work if you put the :stateCode addParameter before the id addParameter?

Comment: @BrianMcGinity - yes, it worked! It doesn't make sense to me why changing positions fixed it though...

Comment: For some reason Oracle likes to know the bind variables in the order they occur in the sql statement. It is as if Oracle is binding by position.  I've had the same problem when writing dynamic sql in stored procedures.

Comment: I'll write this as an answer in case anyone ever search the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversing the order fixed it:

```
db.AddParameter(":stateCode", stateCode);
db.AddParameter(":id", id);
```

For some reason Oracle likes to know the bind variables in the order they occur in the sql statement. It is as if Oracle is binding by position. I've had the same problem when writing dynamic sql in stored procedures.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that many times it's much easier to write sql inside stored procedures as variables in sql statements automatically become bind variables.  If you need to do complex db operations, consider writing it plsql and calling it from c#.